Title of a 1960s black and white haunted house/ghost horror movie
Movie was in English. I don't recall any actor's names. Setting was a Haunted house in the woods. Possibly set in England. Ending was of a woman (I think) trying to escape the haunted house in a car at night. Invisible ghosts were grabbing her hands not allowing her to keep control of the car. A visible ghost runs in front of the car (actor in a fluorescent white suit) and the car crashes into a tree.
Had a 1960s feel. Definitely black and white. Scary. Saw it as kid on TV in the late 1960s or early 1970s.
There was an earlier scene of a person's head mounted on a flat surface--like a small podium--with several long metal pins in his face (in the house). Mouth was open as if screaming when dying.
Never saw it again. Would love to know what it was.

Welcome to Movies & TV!  What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? You might also want to use a more descriptive question title

The black-and-white 1963 film "The Haunting" ends with the female protagonist driving away from a haunted house and being unable to control her car. A woman (thought to be a ghost at the time) runs in front of the car and it crashes into a tree. 
Unfortunately, I cannot find that ending scene online, but here is the film's trailer. 



I am not sure about the scene with the head mounted on a podium, though. 
